# Transform a JSON array to another one

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

That's my JSON data input.

```
"rows": [
          [
             1,
             "GESTORE_PRATICHE",
             1,
             "GESTORE PRATICHE",
             "canViewFolderManagement"
          ],
          [
             2,
             "ADM",
             1,
             "AMMINISTRATORE",
             "canViewFolderManagement"
          ],
          [
             2,
             "ADM",
             2,
             "AMMINISTRATORE",
             "canViewOther"
          ]  
     ]
```

I need to have a new JSON using underscorejs like the following:

```
   [
     {
            "groupID": "1",
            "groupName":"GESTORE_PRATICHE",
            "groupDescr":"GESTORE PRATICHE",
            "functionList": [
                 {
                      "1": "canviewfoldermanagement"
                 }
             ]
        },
        {
            "groupID": "2",
            "groupName":"ADM",
            "groupDescr":"AMMINISTRATORE",
            "functionList": [
                 {
                      "1": "canviewfoldermanagement",
                      "2": "canviewOther"
                 }
             ]
        }
    ]
```

So I need an object array with single elements grouped by ID (first key of each one). I tried with underscore js filter, groupby function but i'm so far...

One of my tries in angular 2:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private http: Http) {
        this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data); // create the source ;
        this.http.get('app/json/profileInput.json')
                .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());

        let profileInput; 
        this.http.get('app/json/profileInput.json')
        .subscribe(res =>{
            profileInput = res.json()
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(profileInput));
            this.profileConstructor(profileInput.rows);
            }
        );


    }

    profileConstructor(profileRows){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(
                _.object(JSON.stringify([_.object([profileRows], ['riga'])], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
            )
       );
    } ;
```

Comment: maybe you add your tries.

Comment: Take a look at the `map` function http://underscorejs.org/#map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and create a new entry if no group exists.

```js
function group(array) {
    var map = new Map;

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var group = map.get(o[0]) || { groupID: o[1], groupName: o[1], groupDescr: o[3], functionList: {} };
        if (!map.has(o[0])) {
            map.set(o[0], group);
        }
        group.functionList[o[2]] = o[4];
    });
    return [...map.values()];
}

var rows = [[1, "GESTORE_PRATICHE", 1, "GESTORE PRATICHE", "canViewFolderManagement"], [2, "ADM", 1, "AMMINISTRATORE", "canViewFolderManagement"], [2, "ADM", 2, "AMMINISTRATORE", "canViewOther"]],
    result = group(rows);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this works well. I modified some particulars but it is ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using array `reduce()` function, you easily convert the existing array into object with desired values.

`reduce` takes two parameter

- first parameter : new variable(can be object, array , or any other type) to return
- second parameter: items of an array.

```js
arr = [
  [
    1,
    "GESTORE_PRATICHE",
    1,
    "GESTORE PRATICHE",
    "canViewFolderManagement"
  ],
  [
    2,
    "ADM",
    1,
    "AMMINISTRATORE",
    "canViewFolderManagement"
  ],
  [
    2,
    "ADM",
    2,
    "AMMINISTRATORE",
    "canViewOther"
  ]
]

arr = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  let flag = false,
    obj = {};
  a.forEach(item => {
    if (item.groupID === b[0] && item.groupName === b[1] && item.groupDescr === b[3]) {
      item.functionList[0][b[2]] = b[4];
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  if (!flag) {
    obj[b[2]] = b[4];
    a.push({
      "groupID": b[0],
      "groupName": b[1],
      "groupDescr": b[3],
      "functionList": [obj]
    });
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```